# Count filtered rows using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

The problem is that RowCount returns 1 instead of visible rows after filtering.

`RowCount = Cells(Rows.Count, colIndex).End(xlUp).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Row`

```
Sub showEightmonth(ws, colName, colIndex)
Dim RowCount As Integer
    ws.Activate
    MsgBox ws.Name
    RowCount = Cells(Rows.Count, colIndex).End(xlUp).Row
    Set Rng = Range(colName & "1:" & colName & RowCount)

    If ws.AutoFilterMode = True Then
    ws.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    End If

    Rng.Select
    Rng.NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
    d = Format(DateAdd("m", -8, Date), "mm/dd/yyyy 07:00:00")
    Range(colName & "1").AutoFilter Field:=colIndex, Criteria1:="<" & d
    RowCount = Cells(Rows.Count, colIndex).End(xlUp).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Row
    'Delete filtered row if RowCount > 1, as row 1 is the header row
    If RowCount > 1 Then
        delRow = colName & "2:" & colName & RowCount
        ActiveSheet.Range(delRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
    If ws.AutoFilterMode = True Then
    ws.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To count the rows that are visible after applying a filter you would have to do this:

```
Sub countNonFiltered()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim colIndex As Long
Dim firstrow As Long
Dim RowCount As Long
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("worksheet name")
colIndex = 1    'let's assume you're interested in column A
firstrow = 2    'Let's assume your header is in row 1 and the data starts from row 2

With sht
    RowCount = .Range(.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp), .Cells(firstrow, colIndex)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count
    Debug.Print RowCount
End With

End Sub
```

For demonstration purposes the code above prints the number of the visible rows in the immediate window.

Keep in mind that this:

```
Cells(Rows.Count, colIndex).End(xlUp)
```

is a range consisting of only one single cell. What you need instead is a range consisting of all the cells that belong to the rows that are still visible after applying the filter.

Also keep in mind that when you're using variables that hold either row or column indexes, they should be declared as `Long`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function and pass the filtered range as a parameter.

```
Function FilteredRowsCount(rng As Range) As Long
Dim rngArea, lcount As Long
      For Each rngArea In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas
        lcount = lcount + rngArea.Rows.Count
      Next
    FilteredRowsCount = lcount - 1
End Function
```